# Yii2 how come I dont need to specify relation name when specify a field within related table?

Tags: php, yii2, relational-database

Currently i have the following code in my model which works perfectly however I am confused due to the face I didn't have to specify the relation name before specifying the field within the related table.

How come this is the case?

Relarion name used within below code is: categoriesToPosts

**Search Model**

```
    $query = Posts::find();
    $query->joinWith(['categoriesToPosts']);

    if(!empty($params['cat'])){
        $query->andFilterWhere(['posts_categories_id' => $params['cat']]);
    }
```

I would have thought within the filterwhere part i'd of had to have the below:

```
['categoriesToPosts.posts_categories_id' => $params['cat']]
```

Comment: if The posts_categories_id field name is the unique in your query ,  i mean is not ambigous , then  in this case is the sql engine itself that resolve  properly the names ..

Comment: @scaisEdge so are you saying that if i had a field with the same name in both tables I'd then have to specify the relation?

Comment: Yes in this case if you don't specify the table name in andFilterWhere clause  ...(not the relation name)  you have an error of ambiguos columns ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = Posts::find();
$query->joinWith(['categoriesToPosts' => function($q) use($params){
    $query->andFilterWhere(['posts_categories_id' => $params['cat']]);
}]);
```

[docs: Joining with Relations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#joining-with-relations)